# Can I make Log4j show logging from Spring classes (specifically Spring Security)?

Tags: spring, spring-security, log4j, log4j2

I have a Spring MVC web app that uses Spring Security 3.2.

It's configured to authenticate users against a MySQL database but users cannot log in.  I suspect Spring Security is not connecting to the MySQL database, but there are no log messages displayed.

What do I add to my log4j.properties file to make the Spring Security logs appear?

I tried adding this to the file ...

```
log4j.category.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

But that didn't work.  Here's my current log4j.properties file ...

```
status = error
name = PropertiesConfig

filters = threshold

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appenders = console

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

log4j.category.org.springframework=DEBUG <<<--- adding this didn't work
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

`log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG`